# Change xml element order using python regex

Tags: python, regex, xml

The goal is to change position of specific xml tag (and it's content) within the given string - ideally using regex.
The string (representing my xml data) has a structure that `<MoveMe>` elements appear before `<Target>` elements.

How to move all `<MoveMe>.*</MoveMe>`   and  `<xsi:MoveMe>.*</xsi:MoveMe>`   occurences after after equivalent `</Target>`or `</xsi:Target>`??

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://some.namespace.org">
    <template>
        <root>
            <body>
                <h2>sample</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <MoveMe>Hans Müller fist
                        content 1 </MoveMe>
                    <Target>
                        <td>a1</td>
                        <td>b1</td>
                    </Target>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr><th>Title</th></tr>
                    <xsi:MoveMe>again</xsi:MoveMe>
                    <xsi:Target>
                        <td>x2</td>
                    </xsi:Target>
                </table>
            </body>
        </root>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://some.namespace.org">
    <template>
        <root>
            <body>
                <h2>sample</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <Target>
                        <td>a1</td>
                        <td>b1</td>
                    </Target>
                    <MoveMe>Hans Müller fist
                        content 1 </MoveMe>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr><th>Title</th></tr>
                    <xsi:Target>
                        <td>x2</td>
                    </xsi:Target>
                    <xsi:MoveMe>again</xsi:MoveMe>
                </table>
            </body>
        </root>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

So far i managed to capture all grupus of `MoveMe` nodes using this pattern:
`s_pat = "(<(xsi:)?MoveMe>(.*?)<\/(xsi:)?MoveMe>)"`

Note that `<table>` element can occur multiple times, but both `MoveMe` and `Target` elements are single.

Comment: parsing XML with regex is similar to parsing HTML with regex. i will refer you to this other SO question for answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: well, this is quite custome case we are dealing with here so we canconsider this just as a string i guess... - other topic would be to parse this to ElementTree object and try to manipulate with child order inside, but this seems to be another story.

Comment: Are _moveme_ and _target_ adjacent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's this simple, something like this

*Find*
`(?s)([^\S\r\n]*<MoveMe>.*?</MoveMe>[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n)?)(.*?<Target>.*?</Target>[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n)?)`
*Replace*
`$2$1`

Generally though, the regex to parse *TAGS* only is below, which might be a bit much for you.

This just parses an atomic tag. To actually handle *nesting* and closure
is another issue entirely.

`<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`